# Finding the third largest even fraction in a given array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to find the third largest even fraction in a given array. I know that Fractions can't be odd or even, but according to guidelines, a fraction is even if the numerator is also even. I've gotten the code to partially work.

Test Case 1:

```
1/2
2/3
2/5
2/7
```

The program will correctly return `2/7` as the third largest even fraction.

Test Case 2:

```
1/2
2/3
2/5
2/7
2/5
```

The program returns `2/5` as the third largest when I am expecting an output of `2/7`.

Test Case 3:

```
1/2
2/3
2/5
2/5
2/7
2/7
```

The program should still return `2/7`, but it's spitting back `2/5`

Can anyone give me a hint or point out where my logic is wrong? The code will work if the values aren't duplicates. Here is my attempt.

```
int main() {
    Fraction largest;
    Fraction secondlargest;
    Fraction thirdlargest;
    Fraction** arr;
    int size;

    std::cout << "How many fractions? ";
    std::cin >> size;

    arr = new Fraction*[size] {nullptr};

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        createFraction(&arr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i]->getNum() % 2 == 0) {
            if (largest < *arr[i]) {
                thirdlargest = secondlargest;
                secondlargest = largest;
                largest = *arr[i];
            }
            else if (secondlargest < *arr[i]) {
                thirdlargest = secondlargest;
                secondlargest = *arr[i];
            }
            else if (thirdlargest < *arr[i]) {
                thirdlargest = *arr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << thirdlargest << " is the third largest even fraction.";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        delete arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have C++11 so why not use vector and unique_ptr and not worry about deleting stuff? (Or even just `std::vector<Faction>`, why does each fraction need to be allocated? That will be faster too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the problem consider what happens when the same fraction is entered twice:

- The first time you will set `largest` correctly
- The second time you will set `second_largest` and this is not correct if you don't want to consider duplicates

You should change the code to use the pattern:

```
if (largest < *arr[i]) {
    thirdlargest = secondlargest;
    secondlargest = largest;
    largest = *arr[i];
} else if (largest != *arr[i]) {
    if (secondlargest < *arr[i]) {
        thirdlargest = secondlargest;
        secondlargest = *arr[i];
    } else if (secondlargest != *arr[i]) {
        if (thirdlargest < *arr[i]) {
            thirdlargest = *arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do a mental step-by-step of your code on the 2nd and 3rd examples:

```
2nd example:
1/2 -> doesn't enter the outside if.
2/3 -> set as largest.
2/5 -> set as second largest.
2/7 -> set as third largest.
2/5 -> set as third largest.
```

Similar phenomenon with the 3rd example, you don't consider duplicates and therefore get incorrect results.